# Redirection PHP

Tags: php, html

I've got this script which is meant to send emails to me but what I want to do is instead of redirecting the user(s) to a different page to display the results I would like it to show the success message or fail message on the same page as the form. I hope I am making my self clear. I am trying to add the php and html to one page.
**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="send_form_email.php" id="contactform" method="post" name=
    "contactform">
            <table width="450px">
                    <tr>
                            <td valign="top"><label for="title">Title
                            *</label></td>

                            <td valign="top"><input maxlength="50" name=
                            "title" size="30" type="text"></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                            <td></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                            <td valign="top"><label for="fname">First Name
                            *</label></td>

                            <td valign="top"><input maxlength="50" name=
                            "fname" size="30" type="text"></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                            <td valign="top"><label for="mname">Middle
                            Name</label></td>

                            <td valign="top"><input maxlength="50" name=
                            "mname" size="30" type="text"></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                            <td valign="top"><label for="lname">Last Name
                            *</label></td>

                            <td valign="top"><input maxlength="50" name=
                            "lname" size="30" type="text"></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                            <td valign="top"><label for=
                            "suffix">Suffix</label></td>

                            <td valign="top"><input maxlength="80" name=
                            "suffix" size="30" type="text"></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                            <td valign="top"><label for="message">Message
                            *</label></td>



      <td valign="top">
                                <textarea cols="25" maxlength="1000" name=
                                "message" rows="6">
</textarea></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                                <td valign="top"><label for="email">Email
                                Address*</label></td>

                                <td valign="top"><input maxlength="80" name=
                                "email" size="30" type="text"></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
                                <input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
                        </tr>


          </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**send_form_email.php:**

```
  <?php
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to      = "test@gmail.com";
    $email_subject = "Your email subject line";


    function died($error)
    {
            // your error code can go here
            echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
            echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
            echo $error . "<br /><br />";
            echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
            die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if (!isset($_POST['title']) || !isset($_POST['fname']) || !isset($_POST['mname']) || !isset($_POST['lname']) || !isset($_POST['suffix']) || !isset($_POST['message']) || !isset($_POST['email'])) {
            died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');
    }

    $title_name  = $_POST['title']; // required
    $first_name  = $_POST['fname']; // required
    $middle_name = $_POST['mname'];
    $last_name   = $_POST['lname']; // required
    $suffix_name = $_POST['suffix'];
    $message     = $_POST['message']; // required
    $email_from  = $_POST['email']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $string_exp    = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
    if (!preg_match($string_exp, $title_name)) {
            $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }
    if (!preg_match($string_exp, $first_name)) {
            $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }
    if (!preg_match($string_exp, $middle_name)) {
            $error_message .= 'The Middle Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }
    if (!preg_match($string_exp, $last_name)) {
            $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }
    if (!preg_match($string_exp, $suffix_name)) {
            $error_message .= 'The Suffix Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }
    if (strlen($message) < 2) {
            $error_message .= 'The Message you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }
    if (strlen($error_message) > 0) {
            died($error_message);
    }
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
    if (!preg_match($email_exp, $email_from)) {
            $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string)
    {
            $bad = array(
                    "content-type",
                    "bcc:",
                    "to:",
                    "cc:",
                    "href"
            );
            return str_replace($bad, "", $string);
    }
    $email_message .= "Title Name: " . clean_string($title_name) . "\n";
    $email_message .= "First Name: " . clean_string($first_name) . "\n";
    $email_message .= "Middle Name: " . clean_string($middle_name) . "\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: " . clean_string($last_name) . "\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: " . clean_string($suffix_name) . "\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: " . clean_string($message) . "\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: " . clean_string($email_from) . "\n";


    // create email headers
    $headers = 'From: ' . $email_from . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email_from . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
?>


<!-- include your own success html here -->

<center>Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.</center>

<?php
}
?>
```

I know it should look something like this but I don't know how to use that in my code:

```
// validation code
// in some div
if($success) {
    // thanks for contacting us
} else {
    // you suck at filling out forms
}
// form goes here
```

Comment: TO display the success/error message on the same page as the html, you must either use AJAX for your form or add the php code to process the form in the same file as your html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP:

```
$mail = mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
if( $mail ){
  // success message
  $msg = "Success - Send Successfully";
  echo "<script>top.location.href = 'index.html#$msg';</script>";
} else {
  // Error message
  $msg = "Error - Email not Send";
  echo "<script>top.location.href = 'index.html#$msg';</script>";
}
```

Use some javascript to get the result from the url into your `index.html` file, in above sample i send the message with hash, now determine the hash from the url with javascript.

```
if(window.location.hash) {
  // Fragment exists
  //Puts hash in variable, and removes the # character
  var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1); 

 // Determine the success or failure
 var patt=/Success/g;
 var result=patt.test(hash);

 if( result ){
    // Success Message
    alert(hash);
 } else {
    // Error Message
    alert(hash);
 }

}
```